# Capturing/Intercepting Android Intents during runtime

Tags: android, android-intent, runtime

Is there any way to capture/intercept Intents of application during runtime without modifying Android framework?
Modifying Android framework might require too much work.
Please help me.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

To view Intents as they happen, run logcat in a shell and filter it down to just the Intents like this:

> adb logcat | fgrep -i intent

(You can also add a filter for just your app's Intents, but that would exclude Intents sent to your app by the system and by other apps.)

This should show Intents such as

> I/ActivityManager(  585): Starting activity: Intent { action=android.intent.action...}

To see system-wide Intents, try the [Intent Intercept app](https://f-droid.org/wiki/page/de.k3b.android.intentintercept).

To see all Intents sent to your own classes, then

- In each BroadcastReceiver, override [onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)).
- In each Activity, call [getIntent()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent()) to get the Intent that started the activity.
- In each Service, override [onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)) to get the Intent that started the Service.

For info on all the standard Intent actions, see [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I'm trying to see all the explicit/implicit Intents of my application. In detail, I need to know which Activity sent which Intent and which Activity received it during runtime. Is it possible?

Comment: @user3491319 I added instructions for viewing Intents via logcat and for capturing Intents sent to your Activities and Services as well as BroadcastReceivers.

Answer (score 1):

Inside instrumentation tests (tried on [UI Automator](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/other-components/ui-automator)) you can use [IntentMonitor](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/runner/intent/IntentMonitorRegistry):

```kotlin
val intentMonitor = IntentMonitorRegistry.getInstance()
intentMonitor.addIntentCallback { intent ->
    // your code here
}
```